# This question was marked as a duplicate. That's OK. But why was it subsequently deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

The question [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/61889/is-the-encirclement-the-result-of-military-victory-and-not-the-cause-of-it) is clearly a duplicate and was correctly closed as such. But then it was also deleted by Community. There doesn't appear to be anything in the question demanding quick deletion. Is there a set of conditions that lead to deletion on top of closure?  Or is there some unique circumstance about this question in particular?

Comment: It's too quick for [Roomba](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). Has the user been deleted? IIRC, that will delete negatively scoring posts automatically. (I can't see the question, I don't have enough reputation.)

Comment: @Glorfindel Looks like the user is deleted -- now user#####

Comment: And the question's score is negative?

Comment: @Glorfindel Zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question was deleted as a side effect of the user being destroyed.

The user was destroyed because, via mod tools, I determined with very high confidence that it was our resident Nazi troll.

Comment: When the user was destroyed, did that have the side effect of cancelling all up- and down-votes? The question is currently listed at 0/0, suggesting the answer is "*Yes*".

Comment: @PieterGeerkens It deletes votes cast by the destroyed user, but AFAIK, it should not invalidate received votes. Are you saying you voted on the question and it's now unrecorded?

Comment: I don't recall if I voted on the question or not. I simply was surprised to see no votes at all when I perused the question.